# How to fix an issue with accordion scrolling in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui-accordion

My accordion works fine on firefox, but on google chrome browser, when clicking on accordion item, whole page scrolls up.
My code in custom.js looks like:

```
/*
        *   Shortcode Accordion (Jquery UI)
        */ 
        $(".accordion").accordion({
            header: '> div.accordion-wrap > h4',
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content"
        });
```